# SharePoint ULS log category -ILDS

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, uls

In SharePoint ULS logs I come across OWSTIME.EXE records few activities under category ILDS.

What could be this actually referring to?

[image: ULS Log]

Comment: To clarify, I would like to know What is ILDS, it is the category against which SharePoint timer service logs its activities.

Comment: Can you provide an example entry from the ULS log?

Comment: @TrevorSeward - Added an image, hope it helps

Comment: Are you sure this isn't a custom timer job?  Usually Microsoft wouldn't put the name of a source file (Fixer.cs) within the log itself like that.

Answer (score 0):

That is the SharePoint Timer Service which is used for [Timer Jobs](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc678870.aspx)

see http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/startups/OWSTIMER.EXE-16494.html

Comment: Hi Ryan. Appreciate your reply. I am aware OWSTIMER is SharePoint Timer Service. Apologies if my question was not clear, I would like to know what is ILDS, which the category against which SharePoint timer service records activities.